# Powershell - Set Version and company name of executable created by Powershell

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, resources, exe

I am developing a `.ps1` powershell script which creates `.exe` file following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/may/windows-powershell-writing-windows-services-in-powershell). I have created `.exe` successfully. Here is a minimal example of the code.

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Status')]
Param(
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Start', Mandatory=$true)]
  [Switch]$Start,               # Start the service

  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Stop', Mandatory=$true)]
  [Switch]$Stop,                # Stop the service
)

$scriptVersion = "1.2.3.4"
$serviceName = Get-Item $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition     # myService
$exeFullName = "MyService.exe"

#  Source Code
$source = @"
  using System;

  public class Service_$serviceName : ServiceBase {

    public static void Main() {
      System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(new Service_$serviceName());
    }
  }
"@

if ($Start) {                   # service started
  Write-Verbose "Starting service $serviceName"
  Start-Service $serviceName # Ask Service Control Manager to start it
  return
}

if ($Stop) {                    # service stopped
  Write-Verbose "Stopping service $serviceName"
  Stop-Service $serviceName # Ask Service Control Manager to stop it
  return
}

# Generate .EXE from the C# source embedded in script
try {
Write-Verbose "Compiling $exeFullName"
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -Language CSharp -OutputAssembly $exeFullName -OutputType ConsoleApplication -ReferencedAssemblies "System.ServiceProcess" -Debug:$false
} catch {
$msg = $_.Exception.Message
Write-error "Failed to create the $exeFullName service stub. $msg"
exit 1
}
```

Now I want to assign attributes to `.exe` file, like `Version`, `Publisher` etc. I have followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblycompanyattribute?view=net-5.0) but I am unable to complete the task. I am using Inno setup to bundle this `.exe` in main exe file. These are the commands to bundle in Inno setup:

```
[Run]
Filename: "powershell.exe";Parameters: "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""{app}\myScript.ps1"" -setup"; WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: runhidden
Filename: "powershell.exe";Parameters: "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""{app}\myScript.ps1"" -start"; WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: runhidden
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: You should post an example of the code you have written so far. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have added the code example. Please have a look.